# how to change the header and logo in TCPDF in codeigniter?

Tags: php, pdf, codeigniter-3, tcpdf

[image]this is the header code, in **view** which is generating pdf, Even I tried to change the suspected code, still it is producing the same output..

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 
 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
  $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
  $pdf->SetAuthor('Change me');
 $pdf->SetTitle('Financial Report');
 $pdf->SetSubject('Yearly Customer Finanacial Report');
 $pdf->SetKeywords('Purchase, Sale, Order, Payment');

  // set default header data
 $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, 
  PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' My PDF', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), 
  array(0,64,100));
  $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the base tcpdf class into Your Own and override the logo logic.

Then call `new YourTcpdf()` instead.

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');


// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_example.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< TCPDF Example 003 >>', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    }

 
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
 // set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);    
$pdf->SetAuthor('Change me'); 
$pdf->SetTitle('Financial Report');       
$pdf->SetSubject('Yearly Customer Finanacial Report'); 
$pdf->SetKeywords('Purchase, Sale, Order, Payment');
  // set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' My PDF', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,100));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));
```

A full example can be found here:
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/